# CakePHP Generate IP Range

Tags: php, cakephp

I am fairly new to CakePHP and have been struggling to figure out how to do this. I need to store IP Addresses in a table with descriptions of what they are assigned to etc. I first create the IP Range e.g. 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 this is not a problem, however I want the IP Range to create all the IP Addresses in another table.

Ip_Ranges (stored as ip2long):

```
Id, Network,     Subnet,        Description
1 , 192.168.0.0, 255.255.255.0, Internal Range
```

Ip_Addresses(stored as ip2long):

```
Address,     Subnet,        Description
192.168.0.1, 255.255.255.0, 
192.168.0.2, 255.255.255.0, 
192.168.0.3, 255.255.255.0,
192.168.0.4, 255.255.255.0,
192.168.0.., 255...
```

You get the picture!

Code so far:

```
public function add() {
    $this->IpRange->create();
    if ($this->IpRange->save($this->request->data)) {
        $ip = ip2long($this->request->data['IpRange']['Network']); 
        $nm = ip2long($this->request->data['IpRange']['Subnet']); 
        $nw = ($ip & $nm); 
        $bc = $nw | (~$nm); 

        while($ip <= $bc ){
            //What should go here to save the $ip???

            $ip++;
        }             
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The IP Range has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The IP Range could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    } 
}
```

So as you can see creating the IP range is just a simple form save, but when this saves I need it to populate the ip_addresses table which is where I'm stuck.

How do I do this? I assume with a while look and just ++ the network address until reaching the broadcast address but I'm not familiar with cakephp and while loops saving to an alternative table.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Try binary operators as the subnet is actually a binary operation (correct me if im wrong). So go from 1 to 255 and insert anything that matches (lastIPByte & lastSubnetByte)

Comment: @ToBe I know how to get the data in the while statement the main issue is to save it in the ip_addresses table. I will edit to show more detail.

Comment: Check the book for how to save associated data, it is pretty detailed explained there. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split netmask, check it and depending on its value set number of iterations for adding IPs?